# Angularjs - Selected value row

Tags: angularjs

I base in this example:
http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/
Demo:
http://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/ngClass/

The example is working ok, but i need to add a button element and when i click in the button, i want to show in a alert, the value of name column, for example "Noodles"

This is my code html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="organizational in organizationals" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
      <td>{{organizational.branch}}</td>
            <td>{{organizational.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createSelectRowClick();">Select</button>
```

This is my js code:

```
$scope.managers = [
 {name: 'Ana Faedo Iglesias'},
 {name: 'Cristina Menendez'},
 {name: 'Daniel Piriz'}
];

$scope.selectedRow = null;

$scope.setClickedRow = function(index){
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
}
$scope.createSelectRowClick = function(){
  if ($scope.selectedRow==null)
  {
    alert("Any rows selected");
  }
  else
  {
    //alert("valuetd" + value td column name, about click row);
  }
}
```

NOTE: The table is in a modal window, if i click in table row, I recover the value of the column, i close the window modal, and after, i can put the column value wherever.

How could do it? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
$scope.createSelectRowClick = function(){
  if ($scope.selectedRow==null)
  {
    alert("Any rows selected");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("valuetd " + $scope.organizationals[$scope.selectedRow].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to know that.